# Setting Font color while saving a value to csv from xsl

Tags: xslt, html

Any idea how to apply a font color to a value in xsl while saving it to CSV.i have tried using font color and span style, it doesnt work.
The code is below

```
<xsl:when test="$priority1 &lt; 3">
<span style="color:#ff0000">
  <xsl:value-of select="$priority"/></span>
</xsl:when>
```

this is saved as CSV.the output displays as
Priority

```
<span style="color:#ff0000">2</span>
<span style="color:#ff0000">2</span>
3
5
```

How do i apply color to a CSV param
Help!!

Comment: Can you explain more clearly? Provide sample input XML and desired output.

Comment: Its not used for XSL tranformation.I am trying to do a static validation for the XSL.The report is saved as csv with the parameters be checked.That is what the code i have pasted implies--if the priority < 3 then highlight it in RED.But when i save the report as csv the tag doesnt work.Any idea on this.

Answer (score 1):

CSV files do not contain any formatting information. They are purely comma-delimited lists of data, and not really for display purposes. In this case, you are adding HTML formatting information into the file, but to CSV, this is just a string of text and means nothing.

If you were to double-click on a CSV to open it, then it would most like open in a Spreadsheet application like Microsoft Excel. Now, Excel would allow you to color the cells, but if you were to try to save it at a CSV file again, it would moan at you about un-supported features, and only the text of the cells saved.

If you were only interested in producing a report to highlight records, then you still have a number of options

1. Save the report as an HTML file
2. Save the report using Excel Xml (assuming you have Microsoft Excel)
3. Save the report in SYLK (Symbolic Link) format

In the latter two cases, both files should be opened automatically in Excel, for example.

If you had no choice to save it as a CSV, I am not sure what other options you have.